# Optional html class in twig template

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a simple reusable twig (generic.html.twig) template which look like:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in list %}
        <li>
            ...
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I use it many times in my code like this:

```
{% include "@Toto/generic.html.twig" with {"list": toto} %}
```

My problem is that I sometimes want to include a CSS class on the `<ul>` generated by my twig template. So sometimes I would like for it to render like this:

```
<ul class="myclass">
```

while other times I'd like for it to render without the class, like this:

```
<ul>
```

How do I implement optional classes in my twig template?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the use of defined

```
<ul{% if ulClass is defined %} class="{{ ulClass }}"{% endif %}>
    {% for item in list %}
        <li>
            ...
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like:

```
{% include "@Toto/generic.html.twig" with {"list": toto, "status": true} %}
```

And check against `status` boolean

```
<ul {{ status ? 'class="myclass"' : '' }}>
```